# Equilibrium constant of the formation of ferric thiocyanate

Tags: thermodynamics, equilibrium, kinetics

I was reading the paper Relaxation Kinetics of Ferric Thiocyanate (Goodall et. al, 1972) and I came across a passage which read

> $\space$ Reaction (1) is the simplest representation of the equilibrium between ferric and thiocyanate ions and their
> complex. The ratio $k_{12}/k_{21}$ is the equilibrium constant
> $K_c$, which has the value $1391{\text {mole}^{-1}}$ at 298°K and ionic
> strength 0.5 mole $\text{kg}^{-1}$ ($\textit 8$)
> $$\ce{[Fe(H_2O)_6]^{3+}}+\ce{SCN^{-}}\underset{k_{21}}{\stackrel{k_{12}}{\rightleftharpoons}} \ce{[Fe(H2O)5SCN]}^{2+}+\ce{H2O} \space\space\space\space\space\space(1)$$

However, the paper later makes clear that reaction (1) cannot be single step

> Reaction (1) is insufficient to explain the mechanism
> of the equilibration, since the relaxation rate decreases
> with increase in the concentration of hydrogen ion in
> the solution. This is explained by introducing eqns.
> (2)-(4). Most of the reaction proceeds through the
> hydroxo complex, which is present in amount determined by the pH and the acid dissociation constant of
> the hexaquo complex, $\ce{K_{OH}} = 1.89 \times 10^{-3} \text{mole}^{-1}$ at
> 298 $^\circ$K and ionic strength 0.5 mole $\text{kg}^{-1}$ ($\textit{10}$).
> $$\ce{[Fe(H_2O)_6]^{3+}} \xrightleftharpoons{\text{fast}} \ce{[Fe(H_2O)_5OH]^{2+}}+\ce{H^+}\space\space\space\space\space\space(2)$$
> $$\ce{[Fe(H_2O)_5OH]^{2+}}+\ce{SCN^-}\underset{k_{43}}{\stackrel{k_{34}}{\rightleftharpoons}}\ce{[Fe(H_2O)_4(OH)SCN]^{+}}\space\space\space\space\space\space(3)$$
> $$\ce{H^+}+\ce{[Fe(H_2O)_4(OH)SCN]^{+}\xrightleftharpoons{\text{fast}}\ce{[Fe(H2O)5SCN]}^{2+}}\space\space\space\space\space\space(4)$$

How then can it be possible that $K_c = k_{12}/k_{21}$ for reaction (1), since it is not elementary?

Comment: Measuring $K_c$ for eqn 1 is ok, as it is $k_{12}/k_{21}$ even if these individual values are unknown.  However, further experiments shows that protons play a role and so the scheme 2-4,. The product of rate constant ratios should produce $K_c$ so $k_{12}$ and $k_{21}$ are not simple rate constants but comprise other terms, according to the expanded scheme.